# Dynamically adding ImageIcon in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Okay, I am a newbie at GUI stuff. I am experimenting with a simple program where you pick a color, width, height and it'll generate a png file with the specified values. My problem is adding the image icon to the label after the my generate function executes. The file is created, but the imageIcon is not displaying in the imagePanel.This is just a test I am creating.

This is where I am having trouble:

```
    private void generateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    int Width=getWidthInput();
    int Height= getHeightInput();
    BufferedImage image= new BufferedImage(Width,Height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    File directory= null;
    BufferedImage generatedPic;
    //drawing portions of image
    for(int i = 0; i < Height; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<Width; j++){
                    int a=255;
                    int r=getRed();
                    int g=getGreen();
                    int b=getBlue();
                    int p= (a<<24)|(r<<16)|(g<<8)|b;
                    image.setRGB(j,i,p);
            }
    }
    try{
            directory= new File("testImg.png");
            ImageIO.write(image,"png",directory);
            System.out.println("Image Has Been Written");
            ImageIcon ii= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("testImg.png"));
            imageLabel.setIcon(ii);
            revalidate();
            repaint();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
    }
    directory.deleteOnExit();   
}
```

This is the whole program:

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JButton submitBtn;
    /**
     * Creates new form MainFrame
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public int getRed(){
        return Integer.parseInt(red.getText());
    }

    public int getGreen(){
        return Integer.parseInt(green.getText());
    }

    public int getBlue(){
        return Integer.parseInt(blue.getText());
    }

    public int getWidthInput(){
        return Integer.parseInt(width.getText());
    }

    public int getHeightInput(){
        return Integer.parseInt(height.getText());
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        imagePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        imageLabel= new JLabel();


        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        red = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        green = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        blue = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        width = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        height = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        submitBtn= new JButton("Generate Image");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mainPanel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(54, 136, 137));
        mainPanel.setAutoscrolls(true);





        jLabel2.setText("color:");

        jLabel3.setText("width:");

        jLabel4.setText("height:");

        submitBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                generateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout imagePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(imagePanel);
        imagePanel.setLayout(imagePanelLayout);
        imagePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            imagePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(imageLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 446, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        imagePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            imagePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(imageLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
        mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(red, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(green, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(blue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(width)
                    .addComponent(height)
                    .addComponent(submitBtn))

                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 43, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(imagePanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(imagePanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(red, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(green, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(blue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(width, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(height, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))

                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(submitBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(297, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jMenuBar1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(54, 136, 137));

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        jMenu3.setText("jMenu3");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }
    private void generateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        int Width=getWidthInput();
        int Height= getHeightInput();
        BufferedImage image= new BufferedImage(Width,Height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        File directory= null;
        BufferedImage generatedPic;
        //drawing portions of image
        for(int i = 0; i < Height; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<Width; j++){
                        int a=255;
                        int r=getRed();
                        int g=getGreen();
                        int b=getBlue();
                        int p= (a<<24)|(r<<16)|(g<<8)|b;
                        image.setRGB(j,i,p);
                }
        }
        try{
                directory= new File("testImg.png");
                ImageIO.write(image,"png",directory);
                System.out.println("Image Has Been Written");
                ImageIcon ii= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("testImg.png"));
                imageLabel.setIcon(ii);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
        }
        directory.deleteOnExit();




    }     




/*    
    private void redActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                   
*/
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField blue;
    private javax.swing.JTextField green;
    private javax.swing.JTextField height;
    private javax.swing.JLabel imageLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel imagePanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField red;
    private javax.swing.JTextField width;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: An alternative to looping over the entire x/y pixels of the Image is to paint to a Graphics object, as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html)

Comment: Consider the two file paths: `"testImg.png"` vs. `getClass().getResource("testImg.png")`. Are they the same?

Comment: @gpasch you don't have to be that rude, he's just trying to learn

Comment: @copeg ahh yes, I used the for loops because later I will need them to get the value of all pixels in an image that the user will specify. So I just did it this way to get familiar with the ImageIO and BufferedImage class. And those two paths are the same.

Comment: @gpasch Ohh yeah I agree! The generated code is horrible. Like I said , I was just experimenting and so that included using NetBeans gui plugin. Now if you don't have a real answer to this question, then don't comment. Thank you, have a nice day:)

Comment: @JoseOrtiz now you're being rude, however I recommend you to redo this code w/o using the GUI builder, this will make your code cleaner and easier to understand for all of us

Comment: Yeah I agree I apologize @gpasch haha

Comment: @Frakcool, okay yes I'll do that. Now, is it necessary to have to have the whole gui in a thread (run()) ? I've created a frame with a panel and buttons and simply instantiated the object in main without the thread and it worked

Comment: It works, but Swing is not Thread safe, the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { ... ` puts your program inside the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), See [What is the advantage of SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264229/what-is-the-advantage-of-swingutilities-invokelater-method)

Comment: Okay awesome Thank you. Do you have any good references or tutorials that I can follow?

Comment: @JoseOrtiz, getClass().getResource() uses the class loader - file must be on class path. I'd recommend checking the URL returned by this call

Comment: @copeg you were right. thank you. the  getClass().getResource()  returned a different path. I simply just used the "testImg.png"

Comment: Thank You very much for your help guys. I Really appreciate it. Thank you for pointing out the "testImg.png" vs. getClass().getResource("testImg.png") situation and thank you very much for the suggestions and reference. This has helped me understand GUI a little better

Comment: @Frakcool thank you

Comment: @copeg and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code has already created a `File`, it makes perfect sense to use that file as the basis for the `URL` for the `ImageIcon`! E.G.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SavedImageDisplayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(200, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        final File file = new File("testImg.png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImageIcon imageIcon;
                try {
                    // use the File as basis for the URL!
                    imageIcon = new ImageIcon(file.toURI().toURL());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, imageIcon);
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Thompson! very clean. We discussed this on the comments above! thank you for your response, very much appreciated!

Comment: *"We discussed this on the comments above!"* Oh my bad! I haven't finished my first coffee of the day & decided I could not bother trawling through the comments above, when it was so simple to create an example. :P

Comment: No worries! You guys are awesome! Thank you!